# simple Q about where to install packages

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

let's say I want to download ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials through

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
```

where do I need to be cd'd into at that time or does it matter?
I am currently in catkin_ws/devel, is that going to be fine?

also, in general, when installing packages, does the same answer apply?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271180/simple-q-about-where-to-install-packages/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
```

from anywhere. You don't need to be in a certain directory to use that command. `apt` should install this into your `/opt/ros/<distro>/share/` directory without you having to be in that directory yourself.

> also, in general, when installing packages, does the same answer apply?

Depends on how you're installing them. If you're using `apt`, like above, then you let it deal with that. If you're installing the source (such as cloning from a git repo for example) then you would compile and install it from the root of your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1